# Hooking Main Menu from Custom Component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a custom component for my WinForms application. It will handle file commands such as New, Open, Save, and Save As.

I've done this before so I'm pretty clear how I want it to work. But I'm wondering if there is any way to have the component automatically hook the related commands in the main form. Or maybe even dynamically add those commands to the main form. This would save me the trouble of having to hook up those commands in each application that uses this component.

I'm not married to using a component if there's a better way. Basically, it is a class that accesses other components like the common dialogs.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What we do is implement an interface in the custom component. Say `IHasFileActions`. Then when the control is loaded in the main form, if it implements `IHasFileActions`, the button commands can be propagated properly.

Comment: This isn't clear to me. What object implements `IHasFileActions`? And what object propagates the button commands? The form or the component? I want the component to do this.

Comment: Your custom component implements `IHasFileActions`. The form is responsible for propagating the actions. (Events are captured in the form anyway.). If you really want to reduce code in main form, you can implement the observer pattern here.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid putting the code in the form so that every app that uses my component will have to duplicate that code. I guess I can Google around and try and figure out what you mean by the "observer pattern".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any slick way to do this.

I ended up just adding a method to my component, which the form must call, that adds all the menu commands and attaches the component's own handlers. The method takes one argument: an instance of the `ToolStripMenuItem` that the commands should be added to.

```
public void CreateMenuCommands(ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
{
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Insert(0, new ToolStripMenuItem("&New", null, MenuNew_Click, Keys.Control|Keys.N));
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Insert(1, new ToolStripMenuItem("&Open...", null, MenuOpen_Click, Keys.Control | Keys.O));
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Insert(2, new ToolStripMenuItem("&Save", null, MenuSave_Click, Keys.Control | Keys.S));
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Insert(3, new ToolStripMenuItem("Save &As...", null, MenuSaveAs_Click));
}
```

It still requires a manual step on the part of the form, but it's a simple matter to call this single method.